# Find out which process blocks my server

Tags: linux, performance, docker

I have a VPS with some Docker containers running, and something strange happens about once a day:

The server stops responding to anything (ping, cloud, ssh, mail, etc.) and when I go to the cloud interface of my provider, I see that 100% of CPU is currently used but 0% of RAM!

So I tried to log CPU usage with the following command :

```
nohup dstat -ta --top-cpu --output systemstats.csv &
```

But the log stops just before the CPU increases, so it does not give me any meaningful information.

What could be causing this? How can I investigate this behavior?

Comment: It might be that the server stopped reporting in to the cloud provider too. Check `dmesg` after an event and check /var/log/* or journalctl -xe

Comment: @jedifans The server does not report to the cloud provider I think, they have their own virtual machines monitoring systems. When I try `journalctl -xe` it says "No journal files were found.". When you say *"after an event"*, do you mean after a peak? If so, I cannot since I have to reboot the server every time this happens... I will look at /var/log/*, what do you think I should look for?